# Error Exception occurred while processing task when using Iap API from Amazon purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, amazon-appstore

followed the instructions on  [amazon developer page](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-implement-iap.html) to be able to add IAP API to my app. But it doesn't work and throws an error:

```
 AbstractCommandTask: Exception occurred while processing task: com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a: AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: null: null
com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a: AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: null: null
    at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.b.a(AuthenticationTokenVerifier.java:94)
    at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:204)
    at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:131)
    at com.amazon.a.a.n.b.b$1.run(SimpleTaskPipeline.java:179)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I downloaded the amazon app tester and added the amazon.sdkteste.json file to the sdcard folder as shown in the instructions and in the app tester app also recognized this file.
I also downloaded the AppstoreAuthenticationKey.pem file and saved it to the app's app/src/main/assets folder. Can anyone tell me what am I missing or can someone give me a solution to fix this problem.

Thank
Below Is My AndroidManifest.xml Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.amazontinhtoannhanh">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TinhToanNhanh"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name = "com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver"
     android:permission = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY"
     android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import com.amazon.device.drm.LicensingService;
    import com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingService;
    import java.util.HashSet;

    import java.util.Set;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_subcire;
     Set <String>productSkus=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LicensingService.verifyLicense(this.getApplicationContext(), new LicensingCallback());
        TinhToanNhanhPurchasingLIstener purchasingListener= new TinhToanNhanhPurchasingLIstener();
        PurchasingService.registerListener(this.getApplicationContext(), purchasingListener);
        btn_subcire= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_subcire);

        btn_subcire.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              PurchasingService.purchase("com.match.payment");
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        PurchasingService.getUserData();
        productSkus =  new HashSet<String>();
        productSkus.add( "com.mathterm.payment" );
        productSkus.add( "com.mathterm2.payment" );
        productSkus.add( "com.mathterm3.payment" );
        productSkus.add( "com.mathterm4.payment" );
        productSkus.add("25");
        PurchasingService.getProductData(productSkus);
        PurchasingService.getPurchaseUpdates(false);
    }
}
```

**LicensingCallback.java:**

```
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.util.Log;

import com.amazon.device.drm.model.LicenseResponse;

public class LicensingCallback implements com.amazon.device.drm.LicensingListener {
public void onLicenseCommandResponse(final LicenseResponse licenseResponse) {
    final LicenseResponse.RequestStatus status = licenseResponse.getRequestStatus();
    Log.d(TAG, "onLicenseCommandResponse: RequestStatus (" + status + ")");
    switch (status) {
        case LICENSED:
            Log.d(TAG, "onLicenseCommandResponse: LICENSED");
            break;
        case NOT_LICENSED:
            Log.d(TAG, "onLicenseCommandResponse: NOT_LICENSED");
            break;
        case ERROR_VERIFICATION:
            Log.d(TAG, "onLicenseCommandResponse: ERROR_VERIFICATION");
            break;
        case ERROR_INVALID_LICENSING_KEYS:
            Log.d(TAG, "onLicenseCommandResponse: ERROR_INVALID_LICENSING_KEYS");
            break;
        case EXPIRED:
            Log.d(TAG, "onLicenseCommandResponse: EXPIRED");
            break;
        case UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            Log.d(TAG, "onLicenseCommandResponse: ERROR");
    } } }
```

**TinhToanNhanhPurchasingLIstener:**

```
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.util.Log;

import com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingListener;
import com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingService;
import com.amazon.device.iap.model.FulfillmentResult;
import com.amazon.device.iap.model.Product;
import com.amazon.device.iap.model.ProductDataResponse;
import com.amazon.device.iap.model.PurchaseResponse;
import com.amazon.device.iap.model.PurchaseUpdatesResponse;
import com.amazon.device.iap.model.Receipt;
import com.amazon.device.iap.model.UserDataResponse;

import java.util.Map;

public class TinhToanNhanhPurchasingLIstener implements PurchasingListener {

private String currentUserId =  null ;
private String currentMarketplace =  null ;
boolean reset =  false ;

@Override
public void onUserDataResponse(UserDataResponse userDataResponse) {
    final UserDataResponse.RequestStatus status = userDataResponse.getRequestStatus();

    switch (status) {
        case SUCCESSFUL:
            currentUserId = userDataResponse.getUserData().getUserId();
            currentMarketplace = userDataResponse.getUserData().getMarketplace();
            break ;

        case FAILED:
        case NOT_SUPPORTED:

            break ;
    }
}

@Override
public void onProductDataResponse(ProductDataResponse response) {
    switch (response.getRequestStatus()) {
        case SUCCESSFUL:
            for ( final String s : response.getUnavailableSkus()) {
                Log.v(TAG,  "Unavailable SKU:" + s);
            }

            final Map<String, Product> products = response.getProductData();
            for ( final String key : products.keySet()) {
                Product product = products.get(key);
                Log.v(TAG, String.format( "Product: %s\n Type: %s\n SKU: %s\n Price: %s\n Description: %s\n" , product.getTitle(), product.getProductType(), product.getSku(), product.getPrice(), product.getDescription()));
            }
            break ;

        case FAILED:
            Log.v(TAG,  "ProductDataRequestStatus: FAILED" );
            break ;
    }

}

@Override
public void onPurchaseResponse(PurchaseResponse purchaseResponse) {
        switch (purchaseResponse.getRequestStatus())
        {
            case SUCCESSFUL:
                PurchasingService. notifyFulfillment(purchaseResponse.getReceipt().getReceiptId(), FulfillmentResult.FULFILLED);
                break;
            case FAILED:
                break;
        }
}

@Override
public void onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(PurchaseUpdatesResponse response) {
    switch (response.getRequestStatus()) {
        case SUCCESSFUL:
            for ( final Receipt receipt : response.getReceipts()) {
                // Process receipts
            }
            if (response.hasMore()) {
                PurchasingService.getPurchaseUpdates(true);
            }


            break ;
        case FAILED:
            break ;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: if anyone has a sample project about this api can leave me a link for reference ?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for it you just need to run the following adb command on the device where you want to run the app:

```
adb shell setprop debug.amazon.sandboxmode debug
```